# Does the phrase "take from something" mean "understand from something"?

Tags: meaning

The *take something from something* mean exectly the same as *understand from something*? For example:

> No that you have watched the movie, I would like to know what you **took from it**.

Comment: In this context, yes. Take a look at the 22nd entry from [this](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/take) dictionary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right, to "take something away from something" means ["to learn something from an experience or activity."](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/take-sth-away)

"Take away" is a phrasal verb, often used to mean "understanding of a particular issue"

Cambridge dictionary defines "take" (verb) as

> to understand something in a particular way

There are a few different ways "take" can be used in related phrases. Here are a few examples:

> 1. She gave a nod, which we *took* to mean that she agreed. (The "nod" was understood as a sign of agreement.)
> 2. If there is one thing that people should *take away* from Black Tuesday, it is that we need regulators. (The *learning* here is that regulators are needed.)
> 3. What do you hope people will *take away* from this? (What is it that you wish people learn or understand from this?)
> 4. The *take away* from this series is that James Harden is a choker; he will never win a championship. (What we understand from watching this 6-game series is that James will always choke and never win a title)

In your example

> Now that you have watched the movie, I would like to know what you *took* from it.

the person is essentially asking "What did you learn [or understand] from the movie?"

---

Edit: Note that the *"took"* in *"He took my book and ran"* has a different meaning, and my answer is specific to OP's context.

Comment: In the particular context of this question, yes. But *I took something away from the baby* does ***not*** necessarily mean *I understood something from the baby*. In fact that's unlikely. It could mean, for instance, *I took candy away from the baby*.

Comment: @JasonBassford Yes, of course. I should have clarified that my answer is specific to OP's context.